# How to replace ActionLink with "a" tag in MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

The code looks as following:

1) Razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
```

But, I'd like to have something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DisplayEditUser(@item.Id)">Edit</a>
```

2) JavaScript:

```
function DisplayEditUser(id) {
    window.jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/UsersAdmin/Edit',
        data: "id=" + id
    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
        var index = window.Administration.GetActiveTabIndex();
        if (index === 0) {
            $('#UsersDiv').html(partialViewResult);
        }
    });
}
```

The item.Id is string. That what I've written didn't work.

How to pass item.Id to JavaScript function?

Comment: `data: { id: id }`

Comment: in your case you can add url: '/UsersAdmin/Edit?id=' +id,       and data:{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass an object to the **data** part of ajax.

```
function DisplayEditUser(id) {
    window.jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/UsersAdmin/Edit',
        data: {id: id},
    }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
        var index = window.Administration.GetActiveTabIndex();
        if (index === 0) {
            $('#UsersDiv').html(partialViewResult);
        }
    });
}
```

Also , you have to pass parameter like **string**.

```
<a href="#" onclick="DisplayEditUser('@item.Id')">Edit</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In browser's debugger the program flow doesn't enter to JavaScript function. The argument in Razor @item.Id is without ''.

Comment: Yes - SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.

Comment: I think @item.Id should be in between ''. Something like this: 'asdasdaasdasdasd'. But, I'm not sure. How to do it?

Comment: @tesicg, use simple brackets when pass the parameter `<a href="#" onclick="DisplayEditUser('@item.Id')">Edit</a>`